# Graph many superimposed lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a matrix `mlinerror` where each column is a time series beginning at row 1 and ending at row 5.

I want to make a graph where there are many superimposed lines that are alpha-blended, preferably in which each line has a different color.

Here is my code:

```
plt <- ggplot(df)

for (i in 1:99) {
    plt <- plt + geom_line(aes(x=1:5, y=mlinerror[,i]), alpha=0.1)
}
```

For some reason, I can copy the line `plt <- plt + geom_line(aes(x=1:5, y=mlinerror[,i]), alpha=0.1)` manually (it'd have to be 99 times) for each column and it graphs all the lines, but this compositing doesn't work for my loop method.

What should I do to make a multiple-line graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this more easily if you reshape your data to long format. Here's an example with fake data:

```
library(reshape2)

# Create fake data with 100 time series columns plus a time variable
set.seed(30)
dat = data.frame(time=1:5, replicate(100,cumsum(rnorm(5))))

# Melt into long format
dat.m = melt(dat, id.var="time")

# Plot with each individual time series in a different colour
ggplot(dat.m, aes(time, value, colour=variable, group=variable)) +
  geom_line(alpha=0.2, show_guide=FALSE)
```

[image]